# Redirecting file and disk IO calls to VHD

Tags: c, windows, winapi, win32com, vhd

Say I am programming a windows application in C/++ that would redirect all file system calls from a particular application to a VHD (virtual hard disk) in a way that the application cannot view or access any other drive. (It does not even know that they exist on the system). How would I go about programming this?

I assume I would have to use something like detours to hook the api calls, but am not sure which apis exactly I need to hook. Also, I would like to be able to do this without any kernel-mode  drivers if possible.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to re-implement the [Windows Sandbox](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-os-platform-blog/windows-sandbox/ba-p/301849). In that case, you'll probably want to start learning about the [Hyper-V API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/) first.

Comment: If you just want to *prevent* the application from accessing some resources like file or registry, then you can use Windows AppContainer technology https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/appcontainer-for-legacy-applications-, good info and sample code are available here https://github.com/zodiacon/RunAppContainer.git